# Plot by datenum

Tags: datetime, octave

I am trying to plot a graph by datetime value.

Consider this example CSV (`streetnoise.csv`):

```
datetime,noise level
2018-12-03 03:31:12.592,10
2018-12-03 03:31:15.832,10
2018-12-03 03:31:17.062,11
2018-12-03 03:31:19.292,12
2018-12-03 03:31:23.532,11
2018-12-03 03:31:25.762,10
2018-12-03 03:31:26.002,23
2018-12-03 03:31:28.242,10
2018-12-03 03:31:34.492,10
2018-12-03 03:31:34.722,9
```

So this just stores street noise measurements as tuples. I want to draw a plot from that, using Octave:

```
# Load the data
pkg load io
csv_data = csv2cell("streetnoise.csv")

# Parse the datetimes
datevalues = datenum(csv_data(2:end,1), "yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS.FFF")
seconds = (datevalues - datevalues(1)) * 24 * 60 * 60

# Get noise levels
noiseLevels = [csv_data{2:end,2}]

# Plot by seconds since start
h = figure(1)
plot(seconds, noiseLevels)
title("Levels per seconds")
xlim([min(seconds) max(seconds)])

# Plot by datenum
i = figure(2)
plot(datevalues, noiseLevels)
title("Levels per datevalues")
```

The content of the first figure is readable:

[image: Working]

However, it is not really understandable, since the reader has to know when measurements started an to calculate the time.

The second figure is just empty:

[image: Not working]

How can I plot with the datenum values? I wanted to try datenum parsing for labelling afterwards, but I didn't even come that far.

When I add `xlim([min(datevalues) max(datevalues)])`, I only get to see the y axis.

Comment: As matzeri explained this is a known problem with OpenGL toolkits due to float (single) precision data types. There is another workaround beside using gnuplot: Substract 1.January 2018 from your date so that the remaining dates fit into singles

Comment: have a look at my answer here addressing the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53242735/4183191

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The graph works with

```
graphics_toolkit("gnuplot")
```

the default "fltk" graph toolkit uses numbers as "single", and it has not enough digit to 
discriminate the difference in seconds between dates. Gnuplot uses "double" and it can discriminate

[image]

Comment: I'm sad to say but fltk isn't the default toolkit since Octave 4.0 where Qt was choosen AS default. But Im still using the cli and fltk

Comment: @Andy always cli and gnuplot here. Fltk has too many issue on my system