# Plot with dates goes wrong

Tags: octave, octave-gui

I run into this problem: when I plot in Octave without x values, it's ok. when I add x values (which are supposed to be dates, but I don't impose the date format), it goes weird

```
ab = rand(96,1);
close all
figure
plot(ab)
```

Gives this figure:

[image: plot without x values]

```
close all
figure
plot(datenum('01-Nov-2020 00:00','dd-mmm-yyyy HH:MM'):1/24/4:datenum('01-Nov-2020 23:45','dd-mmm-yyyy HH:MM'),ab)
```

Gives this figure:
[image: plot with x values]
As you can see, the x values are all within 1 day, so I don't even know why the x tick show more than 1 day...

Anyone would have a smart explanation?

Comment: Hi Lucile, actually yes, I've seen this before. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53229703/legend-outside-plot-does-not-work-with-plotyy-in-octave/53242735#53242735 Unfortunately that question had a bit of a red-herring in the title, so it's hard to search for ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT:** As [Tasos stated in an earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53242735/11089932), it's a *"problem of OpenGL being unable to deal with the precision involved when adding small numbers to a large number"*.

---

From my point of view, that's "just" an Octave bug, MATLAB (tested with MATLAB Online) doesn't show that behaviour. It seems, Octave has problems with small `x` intervals when the actual `x` value is relatively high, cf.

```matlab
subplot(2, 1, 1);
x = linspace(800000, 800000 + 2*pi, 100);
y = sin(x);
plot(x, y);

subplot(2, 1, 2);
x = linspace(0, 2*pi, 100);
y = sin(x);
plot(x, y);
```

The corresponding output is:

[image: Output sine]

It seems, some `x` values are getting "merged"!? I haven't searched in depth for reported bugs on that issue...

But, to work around that issue in your case, you could try plotting the data starting at `0`, and later just adapt the `xticklabels`:

```matlab
% Data
ab = rand(96, 1);

figure(1);

% Plot without dates
subplot(3, 1, 1);
plot(ab);
xlim([1, 96]);

% Plot with dates (standard, faulty)
subplot(3, 1, 2);
dates = linspace(datenum('01-Nov-2020 00:00', 'dd-mmm-yyyy HH:MM'), 
                 datenum('01-Nov-2020 23:45', 'dd-mmm-yyyy HH:MM'), 
                 size(ab, 1))
plot(dates, ab);
datetick('x', 'dd-mm-yyyy HH:MM');
xlim([dates(1), dates(end)]);

% Plot with dates (custom, correct)
subplot(3, 1, 3);
# For plotting, subtract start date
dates_for_plot = dates - datenum('01-Nov-2020 00:00', 'dd-mmm-yyyy HH:MM')
plot(dates_for_plot, ab);
datetick('x', 'dd-mm-yyyy HH:MM');
# Add custom xticklabels with re-added start date
xlim([dates_for_plot(1), dates_for_plot(end)]);
xticklabels(cellstr(datestr(xticks + datenum('01-Nov-2020 00:00', 
                                             'dd-mmm-yyyy HH:MM'))));
```

That'd be the output:

[image: Output data]

Comment: See the link I posted in the comments. This has come up before :)

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou Argh, haven't found that! (Even the workaround is the same.) Obviously a duplicate then. :-)

Comment: Well, kinda, you've isolated more or less the same problem / solution, but it may be worth keeping both questions, since the other one started off weird; this seems like a more targeted question / answer. I'd leave it, and keep the link in case it offers complementary details. :)

Comment: Awesome! it works. cheers! yes sorry I had searched for the same problem but obviously didn't find it.