# Resize legend box in octave

Tags: matlab, octave, legend

When I plot some graph in Octave and create a legend, the box of the legend is always larger than necessary. It even hides parts of the actual graph. Therefore, how can we resize the box surrounding the legend or change the opacity of the background color.
I found a [solution for Matlab](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/58914-resizelegend-varargin) which unfortunately does not work with Octave. Any ideas?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53229703/legend-outside-plot-does-not-work-with-plotyy-in-octave, there are some useful tips in how to resize and move the legend in Octave

Comment: Thanks @am304, this indeed solves the problem.